# Symfony2 SyliusRbacBundle role asigment error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() NestedSetRolesResolver.php

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I am implementing SyliusRbacBundle along with FOSUserBundle, I set a secure area just to test if every thing is working but when I browse to that route I got a the following error:

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" at /home/daniel/web/tests/tmootb/vendor/sylius/rbac/Resolver/NestedSetRolesResolver.php line 48
```

When the user is created via FosUserBundle column 'authorization_roles' is filled with this information:

```
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@00000000318556cb000000002fabcd7d
```

Not a big surprise I got that error, that's not an array or ArrayCollection as expected. So, I am not assigning the roles correctly but I am not sure how to do it upon user creation or user promotion. Here is how my User model looks like:

```
/**
 * Class User
 * @package App\AppBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements IdentityInterface
{

/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $authorizationRoles;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->authorizationRoles = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get roles.
 *
 * @return RoleInterface[]
 */
public function getAuthorizationRoles()
{
    return $this->authorizationRoles;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function addAuthorizationRole(RoleInterface $role)
{
    if (!$this->hasAuthorizationRole($role)) {
        $this->authorizationRoles->add($role);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function removeAuthorizationRole(RoleInterface $role)
{
    if ($this->hasAuthorizationRole($role)) {
        $this->authorizationRoles->removeElement($role);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function hasAuthorizationRole(RoleInterface $role)
{
    return $this->authorizationRoles->contains($role);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = parent::getRoles();
    foreach ($this->getAuthorizationRoles() as $role) {
        $roles = array_merge($roles, $role->getSecurityRoles());
    }
    return $roles;
}
}
```

I had a look at how they do it here: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Component/Core/Model/User.php

I am stuck there, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out that I wasn't adding the relationship properly, so I haven't had the intermediate table between users and roles. I added the annotations as follow:

```
    /**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sylius\Component\Rbac\Model\RoleInterface")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sylius_user_role",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true, nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")}
     *      )
     */
    private $authorizationRoles;
```

Then updated the database, override the FOSUserBundle profile edit form, and everything is working now.